# XCode 7 auto-completion doesn't work properly

Tags: swift, parse-platform, autocomplete, swift2, xcode7

It seems XCode 7 (beta) doesn't get auto-completion well.
In my case it doesn't auto-complete my Parse Objects at all...

```
PFQuery(className:"User").getObje // Doesn't propose any completion, compilation works well
```

Someone solved it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced this problem in xcode 7 beta 2. The solution is to specify to xcode the directory in which the framework is located. You can do so by clicking on your project, then choosing Build Settings and search for "framework search path" after that double click on the right side of the row and click the plus sign and add the path to the directory.

NOTE: DON'T choose recursive way. This will not work. just specify EXACTLY in which directory is the Parse framework that is used in your project located.

Comment: what if its just a header file local to the project itself?

Comment: Thanks a ton mate for this tip! It's a shame though that this bug exists even in XCode 7.0.1 final build